# Compiling yelp under Mac OS X

Tags: macos, homebrew, glib, yelp

I am trying to compile both meld and KeePassX again under the Mac OS X environment with the help of Homebrew.  I am using an iMac running OS X 10.10.  I am currently at the stage of building the jhbuilder required to build the mac package.  At this moment, I am stuck at the point that I installed glib through Homebrew, but it keeps on saying that I did not have it installed.  The messages are as follows:

```
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for gsed... no
checking for sed... /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
checking for GLIB - version >= 2.0.0... Package glib-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `glib-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'glib-2.0' found
no
```

*** Could not run GLIB test program, checking why...
    *** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
    *** exact error that occured. This usually means GLIB is incorrectly installed.
    checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
    checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
    Package gio-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gio-2.0.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'gio-2.0' found
    configure: error: glib-compile-schemas not found.
    + exit 1

```
brew ~/Source/yelp$ sudo brew install glib
Warning: glib-2.42.2 already installed
```

Is there any way for me to solve this problem?

Comment: configure: error: Package requirements (
 gio-2.0 >= 2.38.0
 gio-unix-2.0
 gtk+-unix-print-3.0
 gtk+-3.0 >= 3.13.3
 libxml-2.0 >= 2.6.5
 libxslt >= 1.1.4
 libexslt >= 0.8.1
 sqlite3
 webkitgtk-3.0 >= 1.3.10
 yelp-xsl >= 3.12.0
) were not met:

Comment: Somebody told me that I still have bison missed, and now I did it.

Comment: Now I am reinstalling glib and gettext.  There is no -dev version for homebrew, so I just force uninstall and reinstall them.